# checker framework, is there any way to silence/disable type.anno.before.modifier warning?

Tags: java, checker-framework

I thought I'd give checker framework a go, but I'm getting a lot of this

```
/Users/calebcushing/IdeaProjects/ppm/scaf/src/main/java/com/xenoterracide/scaf/Config.java:22: warning: [type.anno.before.modifier] write type annotation @NonNull() immediately before type, after modifiers [abstract]
  abstract Map<String, SkeletonConfiguration> getTemplates();
```

for this code

```java
  @Nullable
  abstract String getWorkdir();
```

it seems to be suggestion that I should write

```java
  abstract @Nullable String getWorkdir();
```

but that goes against the JLS, is there anyway to disable this?

Comment: "but that goes against the JLS" why so?

Comment: @AndyTurner https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3

Comment: @AndyTurner checkstyle has more info https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_modifier.html#ModifierOrder

Comment: if you read JLS 8.4.3, it says "The rules for annotation modifiers on a method declaration are specified in §9.7.4 and §9.7.5.". If you read JLS 9.7.4 it says "It is customary, though not required, to write declaration annotations before all other modifiers, and type annotations immediately before the type to which they apply.". Nullable is a type annotation, it applies to the return type, so JLS says the customary position is where checker is saying to put it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You said, "that goes against the JLS", but it does not.  It's legal Java, and it is better style.
2. The [Checker Framework Manual](https://checkerframework.org/manual/) describes how to [suppress warnings](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#suppressing-warnings), for example via the `@SuppressWarning("type.anno.before.modifier")` annotation or the `-AsuppressWarnings=type.anno.before.modifier` command-line argument.

Comment: > and it is better style.

I don't really agree with that, especially not if you're doing something like JPA with validation, and also as a DTO (for jackson) where you might have 10 annotations on something.

Comment: https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_modifier.html#ModifierOrder

Answer (score 0):

> but that goes against the JLS

Answering purely for this statement: checker is implementing what is described in [JLS 9.7.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.4):

> It is customary, though not required, to write declaration annotations before all other modifiers, and type annotations immediately before the type to which they apply.

As indicated [in the Javadoc of Checker's `Nullable`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/qual/Nullable.html):

> `Nullable` is a type annotation

hence it should appear immediately before the type to which it applies, namely, the method's return type.

---

You also linked [JLS 8.4.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3) in a comment. This shows the grammar production `MethodModifier`:

```
MethodModifier:
    (one of)
    Annotation public protected private
    abstract static final synchronized native strictfp
```

This isn't directly relevant: for one thing, it says you can only use one of these modifiers, so it can't tell you anything about ordering. But if you check [JLS 19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-19.html), you can find the context in which `MethodModifier` appears:

```
MethodDeclaration:
    {MethodModifier} MethodHeader MethodBody

MethodModifier:
    (one of)
    Annotation public protected private
    abstract static final synchronized native strictfp

MethodHeader:
    Result MethodDeclarator [Throws]
    TypeParameters {Annotation} Result MethodDeclarator [Throws]
```

So, checker is telling you to put the annotation as specified in the `MethodHeader` production.